# is it possible to use utl_file_dir = '*' scope = spfile in 12c

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-12c, plsql

Oracle 12c has deprecated  `utl_file_dir = '*' scope = spfile`,
but I need to use this functionality. Is there any option to do it?

Is it possible to give permission using Java classes?

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated does not mean it can not be used, so yes, you can use it:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Sep 26 15:29:05 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter system set utl_file_dir='*' scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL>
```

But keep in mind, it is desupported starting with 18c: [Desupport of UTL_FILE_DIR Initialization Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/initialization-parameter-changes-oracle-database-18c.html#GUID-C03F4062-9AB6-4FFE-8CF8-28F8AF014783), the parameter does not exist anymore.

```
[oracle@o73 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 26 15:28:50 2018
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter system set utl_file_dir='*' scope=spfile;
alter system set utl_file_dir='*' scope=spfile
                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM
```

12.2 example:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Sep 27 11:01:50 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show parameter utl_file_dir

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
utl_file_dir                         string      *

SQL> !ls -l /home/oracle/hello.txt
ls: cannot access /home/oracle/hello.txt: No such file or directory
SQL> DECLARE
  L_HANDLER UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  L_HANDLER := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('/home/oracle', 'hello.txt', 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUTF(L_HANDLER, 'Hello World!');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(L_HANDLER);
END;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> !cat /home/oracle/hello.txt
Hello World!
```

Comment: there is a procedure which reads and write to a file using utl_file , in 11g we didnt create any directory instead alter system set utl_file_dir='*' scope=spfile;  but in 12.2.0.1.0 we are not able to perform the same action without creating directory....

Comment: more over it will be little bit difficult to create directory for  each folder locations since we have hundreds of folders where we creating files and reading from file...

Comment: @muhammadshafi I added an example that shows it works in 12.2 as well.